# Pass subdomain as parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, subdomain, isapi-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I'm new to ISAPI_Rewrite & I'm terrible with regular expressions. I'm in need of a rewrite rule for [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) that will remove the subdomain and pass it as a parameter. For example:

```
mysubdomain.mydomain.com
```

should become

```
mydomain.com/Landing.aspx?ID=mysubdomain
```

I've *found* a regex that seems to match all subdomains except `www`, but I'm not sure how to then pass the subdomain as a parameter as the example above shows.

```
^((?:(?!www).)*)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I'm using the full version of ISAPI_Rewrite so this rule will be at the site-level.

---

Global rule:

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.89

#Disable extentionless processing for ASP.Net v 4.0
RewriteRule (.*)eurl.axd/.* $1

# Don't rewrite urls that are inside the assets folder or have the following extentions
RewriteRule ((^/Assets/.*)|(.*\.axd.*)|(.*\.asmx.*)|(.*\.png.*)) $1 [NC,L]

#Rewrite URL, pass last portion of URL to Landing.aspx + purl
RewriteRule  (.*) $2/landing.aspx\?id=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)(?<!^www)(\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Landing.aspx?ID=%1 [L,QSA]
```

PS: Looks like your global rule is in conflict with above rule of mine. I would therefore suggest you to have your global rule like this to avoid conflict:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ landing.aspx?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /Landing.aspx?ID=%1 [NC,L]
```

You did not specify if you want a 301-redirect or a rewrite,so in case you want it to be redirect, use [NC,R=301,L] instead of [NC,L].

Comment: I'm only getting `id=/` in the querystring.

Comment: You may want to add the following lines in your httpd.conf to enable logging and take a look at how the request is processed: #enabling rewrite.log 
RewriteLogLevel 9 
#enabling error.log 
LogLevel debug

Comment: And how exactly did you adjust the rule?

Comment: I didn't adjust the rule. If I knew enough to adjust the rules, I wouldn't be asking the question :)

Comment: but you needed to set your domain name instead of !^www\.mydomain\.com$ and ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$, right?